# Why Enzyme test unworking in React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

**I need to test Button component**

**it's Button :**

```
import React from "react";
import  './Button.css'


const Button = props => {
    return(
        <button className={"Button"}
        onClick={props.onClick}
        disabled={props.disabled}
        >
            {props.children}
        </button>
    )
}
export default Button
```

It's my Button.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Button from "./Button";

    it('has a title class', () => {

        const wrapper = shallow(<Button/>);

        expect(wrapper.hasClass('Button')).to.equal(true);
```

**I'm add enzyme to react. In the console I has an error:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGP5E.png)

tell me how to solve the problem, i'm new in React.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `hasClass` on the `button` element instead of the `wrapper`:

```
expect(wrapper.find('button').hasClass('Button')).to.equal(true);
```

Comment: Yes, ty, but the error do not missing =( i think it's in config, but dont know where